# Redirect Custom domain to specific firebase hosted app URL route with masking

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-domain-api

I have a SPA hosted using firebase hosting. I currently have a custom domain connected to the app.

> i.e mycustomedomain.com directions users to myapp.firebaseapp.com

. However I want to achieve now is redirect multiple custom domains to specific app url routes. while keeping the address in the url bar as the original customedomain  i.e

```
mycustomdomainB.com --> myapp.firebaseapp.com/routeB
mycustomdomainC.com --> myapp.firebaseapp.com/routeC
mycustomdomainD.com --> myapp.firebaseapp.com/routeD
mycustomdomainE.com --> myapp.firebaseapp.com/routeE
```

is this achievable with firebase hosting? if so how? Can I acheive this using permanent redirect through domain provider(google domains)?

Comment: Did you figure that out? I'm also looking for something like it.